# How to call a folder as an asset folder outside eclipse using libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, file-handling

I am able to use the assets folder to call my assets but in an old project(lost) i was calling all my resources from a folder on my desktop and i forget how to do this maybe along the lines of new external... something i am not sure and have tried looking it up etc but maybe im just not wording it right.

Comment: I would not recommend using an external folder for this exact reason you have run into.

Comment: You would recommend me not using an external folder because it is hard to do?

Comment: Not at all, I'm just questioning why you would want to use an external folder when LibGDX is designed for you to use the assets folder in the android module. Is there a special reason your keeping your resources external?

Comment: oh this is because when i used an external folder in my old project everything refreshed correctly like if i changed my tilemap and then ran my game the changes would be there but that doesn't work like that in the pre-designed one

Comment: As Jason mentioned, it should work just fine. Your project setup must be incorrect. I've also noticed you've asked this question 3 times. I recommend reading the libGDX eclipse setup tutorial to resolve your issue.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans%29